# Linux kernel didn't start correctly after boot

Tags: kernel, grub-legacy

after my first kompilation of linux-kernel (release 3.11) I copy kernel to /boot folder and then run

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

because my system is using grub. Then I saw my kernel in grub menu like "linux-kernel 3.11" But while booting kernel I gave message:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/3026586a-c06a-4ae3-8deb-381252d74515 does not exist.
Dropping to shell!

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8ubuntu1) build-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs):
```

And I don't know why my system is didn't load kernel corectly. I'm totally new in linux-kernel and I'm not familiar with this.

I add to my kernel configuration each option for NETFILTER.
I have in my .config option CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y 
and in grub.cfg option
     set root='hd0,msdos1'
the same like in other out of the box kernels that works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit this website. They can help you..!
http://www.upubuntu.com/search/label/System

How Install/Upgrade to Linux Kernel 3.11.6 in Ubuntu/Linux Mint

Is the easy way to install a new kernel 3.11.6

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.